# Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String' what should i do?

Tags: java, string

I have written

```
+String.format("%02d",sec)+":"+String.format("%02d",milliSec);
```

I have been trying to create a stopwatch app in android studio. This type of error is always coming. So the first line has a red underline and tells me  "Operator '+' cannot be applied to'java.lang.String'" Anybody got an idea of what should I do?

Comment: What's that leading `+` for?

Comment: `String.format("%02d:%02d",sec, milliSec);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` for String concatenation should only be used with two operands:

```
"Hello "+"World"
```

But it does not work without a leading operand

```
+"Hello"
```

Instead of

```
+String.format("%02d",sec)+":"+String.format("%02d",milliSec)
```

you could use

```
String.format("%02d",sec)+":"+String.format("%02d",milliSec)
```

But there us a better solution. You can use a single `String.format` for both values:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d",sec,milliSec)
```